# How do I set up Oracle ONS in spring boot microservice using PoolDataSource.setONSConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle, ucp

I have read the ONS part of the Oracle documentation on this. It says it requires 3 parameters of localport remoteport and nodes. Can someone post an example of how these 3 parameters would look filled out?

I tried setting my local host port, and also the local host port of my oracle database team, I’ve also tried setting the address of the nodes. However it looks like the formatting might be wrong.

I’m getting ONS failed to connect, server timeout when I try running the microservice.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell the JDBC/UCP jar version being used?
Staring 12c, calling PoolDataSource.setONSConfiguration() is optional. If you need ONS or fast connection failover feature in your application, you can simply set PoolDataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true), this should be good enough.